# Is there a command you can use to get a list of all features that are currently active in an org?

Tags: tooling-api, scratch-org-definition-file

Looking to make a near-perfect scratch org definition without using org shapes. I see there may be a way to do it with the tooling api but I'm not exactly sure how. It'd be nice to have an sfdx command for it.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a built-in command, but this is where Salesforce DX plugins can help. [browserforce](https://github.com/amtrack/sfdx-browserforce-plugin), written by [Matthias Rolke](https://github.com/amtrack), is a plugin that allows you to retrieve an org configuration and deploy it to any other org (not even *just* Scratch Orgs, but any org you have admin permissions in), even some settings that are not supported by the metadata API. There are likely other similar plugins out there as well if you take the time to look.